# Foreach loop through JArray only returning first value

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON array which is returned from a web service call. I am ultimately trying to insert all employee data into a SQL database, however if I can get it to just write to the console for now I am sure I can work the rest out. My array returns back a few hundred employee records, however when I run through the loop to try and print first middle last for each employee, I only get the first employee record returned. Anyone have any ideas for how to solve my problem? Here's my code:

```
var i = 0;
foreach (var employee in jsonObj)
{
    var firstName = jsonObj["workers"][i]["person"]["legalName"]["givenName"].ToString();
    var middleName = jsonObj["workers"][i]["person"]["legalName"]["middleName"].ToString();
    var familyName = jsonObj["workers"][i]["person"]["legalName"]["familyName1"].ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(firstName + " " + middleName + " " + familyName);
    i += 1;
}
```

EDIT: Rather than copy/pasting the entire json schema I'll link to it - [ADP Worker V2 schema](https://developers.adp.com/articles/api/worker-v2-api). You'll want to expand out the GET/hr/v2/workers section to see the sample.

Comment: use the debugger.. and check the value of `i` during your loop use `i++;

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the jsonObj, but my guess would be that it has only one employee. What does the debugger say?

Comment: i does nothiong here.

Your foreach is the loop......but cannot see how your json object is defined.
.

Comment: I'm using i because I need to increment through each item in the array, and that was the best way I knew how. I am very positive there's more than one employee as I'm printing all the returned data before I run the foreach loop.@AntDC

Comment: But is there more than one employee in the enumerable of your jsonObj? From your code, I suspect that the list of employees is further up the tree. I'd set a breakpoint in your debugger and take a thorough look at  the structure of the jsonObj object. At the very least edit your question to show the structure of the class behind jsonObj.

Comment: I set a breakpoint on the jsonObj and I can see multiple employees in the data for the object. The formatting looks correct, but how would I check the enumberable part you mentioned?

Comment: I think I know what's going on, but I honestly can't help any further until you provide the class definition of jsonObj, and any relevant classes it may contain. Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: @FraukeNonnenmacher thanks - just updated my post. It's a link to ADP's website where you can see the schema.

Comment: Your loop conditions and your loop body code have nothing to do with each other. You are assuming that the quantity of `jsonObj` contents can be used to determine `jsonObj["workers"]` quantity? Instead perhaps you need to iterate over `jsonObj["workers"]`?

Comment: @crashmstr thanks - i did this and it actually went to the second employee and listed their name... however on the third iteration it said "object reference not set to instance of an object"

Comment: @pburk23 you might need to check that each has the fields you are looking for (i.e. the data might not exist for all of the workers).

Comment: @crashmstr yep, took out the middle name and it is now processing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your jsonObj is not a collection of employees, therefore you can't use `foreach` on it and get the expected results. Since your actual schema is very complicated, here's an example on how to get the data with a `foreach` loop with more simplified classes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Company company = // Whatever you do to retrieve your company
    foreach (var employee in company.Employees)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(employee.Person.Name);
    }
}

public class Company
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the `Company` class has a list of employees. You can use `foreach` on that because you're looking at a list, which is a collection. Another good practice to adopt is to use dot notation, i.e. `employee.Person.Name`, which does not have the danger of misspelling the property you're looking for, although you still have to check for null values.